# Replacement Of All Windows/System Files And Folders

Tags: windows-7

I want to replace all Windows/System Files, that are not affected/modified by user activity in order to fix my Windows 7 installation.

I have made a goal, that I want to fix the computer without reinstalling the OS.

I need ideas, as to what I ned to/can replace?

Ok, so I been experiencing issues like 0xF4 BSOD's. I've been trying to learn WinDBG in order to determine what the problem is.

If anyone is up to the challenge, I can post a MEMORY DMP File.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned what your problems are, there may be a far simpler way to get your machine working correctly. That said, to answer your question, the following may be of help to you. Before attempting anything, you should of course make sure your data is fully backed up, as any number of unexpected situations could occur.

---

1. You can try to run `sfc /scannow` from an administrative command prompt, which will check the integrity of system files and attempt to recover failures it finds.
2. You can perform an "in-place upgrade" of Windows 7, which should reinstall the operating system *without* removing any user files. This requires your machine to be in a state where it can boot, and running an installation DVD from within Windows. Some further instructions are [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.html). Whilst this *is* reinstalling the OS, it isn't doing a clean installation. I believe this is probably what what you mean, as replacing every system file *is* installing the OS.